# Docker swarm can't create overlay network

Tags: docker

On two machines with IP addresses `10.0.0.3` and `10.0.0.10` I was experimenting with docker swarm. First I successfully created the swarm on `10.0.0.3`. Then I joined the swarm from `10.0.0.10`.
After that I left the swarm again at `10.0.0.10` and joined as it as a manager. Then I started getting errors. The first one was using `docker node ls` on the first manager (`10.0.0.3`):

```
It's possible that too few managers are online. Make sure more than 
half of the managers are online.
```

I've tried all kinds of things and at one point was able to do

```
docker swarm init --force-new-cluster --advertise-addr 10.0.0.3
```

I could join from `10.0.0.10` again with the new token. And to create a new network on the manager server:

```
docker network create -d overlay db
```

The response is:

```
Error response from daemon: This node is not a swarm manager.
Use "docker swarm init" or "docker swarm join" to connect this
node to swarm and try again.
```

But `docker node ls` says:

```
ID                            HOSTNAME            STATUS    AVAILABILITY   MANAGER STATUS   ENGINE VERSION
xyipo03a5mm2mwy1d1p1fmkeq *   name                Ready     Active         Leader           20.10.16
```

`docker swarm leave`:

```
Error response from daemon: You are attempting to leave the swarm on 
a node that is participating as a manager. Removing the last manager
erases all current state of the swarm. Use `--force` to ignore this message.
```

And `docker info` says:

```
Swarm: active
  NodeID: xyipo03a5mm2mwy1d1p1fmkeq
  Is Manager: true
  ClusterID: woll445lh814qrrivc68cjayo
  Managers: 1
  Nodes: 1
  Default Address Pool: 10.0.0.0/8  
  SubnetSize: 24
  Data Path Port: 4789
  Orchestration:
   Task History Retention Limit: 5
  Raft:
   Snapshot Interval: 10000
   Number of Old Snapshots to Retain: 0
   Heartbeat Tick: 1
   Election Tick: 10
  Dispatcher:
   Heartbeat Period: 5 seconds
  CA Configuration:
   Expiry Duration: 3 months
   Force Rotate: 0
  Autolock Managers: false
  Root Rotation In Progress: false
  Node Address: 10.0.0.3
  Manager Addresses:
   10.0.0.3:2377
```

To create a network it needs to be the manager. According to the information this host is the manager. But when I try to create a network, it says it's not the manager.

I've got docker containers running on the manager server but they are not running in the swarm.

How can I reset all this, so docker swarm works like expected?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Manager is Ubuntu 22 and worker is ubuntu 20. However I noticed Docker Engine on Ubuntu 22 is older, must have installed the wrong one. Maybe that's the cause.